# Google play store filter

Tags: android, google-play

I was wondering if there is any filter I can set for my app so that it shows only to devices on the play store which has a SIM card or is atleast a CDMA device. I could not find anything after searching the net so I could use some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm" android:required="true"/>
```

I don't know that you'll need both if you include `.gsm`, but it can't hurt. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) for more information.